# Openlayers draw curly brackets

Tags: openlayers

My goal is to have predefined shape of curly brackets over a vector layer in openlayers. It should be rotatable and resizable. Is there is a way to achieve this using openlayers?

Comment: You'll need to show what you have done so far for anyone to give you solution, if you want suggestions then go to forums, stack overflow doesn't encourage this

Comment: Please do some research. I could find answers with just a google search. If you end up asking a question within 10 minutes of a problem the research is insufficient.

Comment: @Rishav What i did was drew shape as a line string.But I was unable to edit this feature as single unit of feature.